# The given key was not present in the dictionary when creating application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I tried to [create an application in Azure AD](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_applications) with the following information:

```js
{
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "displayName": "O365 Test",
    "web": {
        "redirectUrls": ["RedirectUrl"],
        "logoutUrl": "LogoutUrl"
    }
}
```

it threw an error stating "The given key was not present in the dictionary".

After removing the `logoutUrl` it works, but the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/web) lists this as a valid property for the `web` object. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you provide the actual request (feel free to replace `xxx` for the actual domain if you want to mask the URIs)? Just using prototypes like this can mask potential errors in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting the issue. The value of logoutUrl should be a secure url (HTTPS). Sounds like this is not explicit from the documentation. We will have the documentation fixed. Also we will have the error message corrected to be more descriptive of the issue.